# Why is my nodejs app not starting on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-16.04, web-deployment, pm2

I can't start my nodejs app using "pm2 start app.js" because according to my logs there are alot issues. The logs seem too general and I would like to break the problems down. Is there a way I can do just that. Maybe its a module missing or I didn't add a catch somewhere.[image: Pm2 logs]

Comment: It would be helpful to have more than just the last 15 lines of the log. But in the third line it says, "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", so there is definitely a module missing.

Comment: Thats all I am given. I'm currently searching how to get all the logs.

Comment: start with `node app.js` and include those errors

Comment: `pm2 logs` should get you all the logs @Anthony